# The Keys problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Another challenge:
A calculator has two special keys:

- A key transforms a number x in the number 2x.
- B key transforms a number x in the number 2x - 1.

Is it true that if you start with any positive integer, it is possible to press a special key sequence in such a way as to obtain finally the fifth power of an integer?

By simple inspection one realizes that the powers of 2 greater than 1 you can get a fifth power using the A key, but will be possible with other numbers?

Comment: "Is it true that if you start with any positive integer, it is possible to press a special key sequence in such a way as to obtain finally the fifth power of an integer? " do you mean of the same integer that u started with?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: I claim that for any $k \in \Bbb{N}$, it is possible to obtain any integer from $2^kx-(2^k-1)$ to $2^kx$ inclusive. Hence, it suffices to show that there exists some $k \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $x^5 \in [2^kx-(2^k-1), 2^kx]$. I claim that $k=\lceil \log_2 x^4 \rceil$ would work.

Comment: Can anyone clarify this question? I'm reading it as "there exists a sequence of moves $\mathcal S$ such that for any starting integer $n$, after performing $\mathcal S$ one is left with the number $\mathcal S(n)$ which is a fifth power."

Comment: I see two ways to generalize this problem. One is to change the polynomial $x^5$ as Alexander Gruber mentioned in his answer, and the other is to increase the number of buttons as follows. Let $r>2$ be an integer, then define $B_i$ to be transformation $x\mapsto rx-i$ for $i=0,1,\dots,r-1$. I believe all of my proofs can be adapted to this general case.

Answer (score 3):

In this post, I shall interpret the problem as follows. For any positive integer $n$, if we start with $n$ and perform some sequence of the keystrokes $A,B$, we will reach a fifth power of a positive integer. It should be noted that Chris Culter resolved the interpretation with quantifiers reversed in another answer.

Hold $n$ fixed throughout.

**Lemma 1**. *For any nonnegative integer $k$ and any integer $x$ in the interval $[2^kn-2^k+1,2^kn]$, there is a sequence of keystrokes which results in $x$ starting at $n$.*
*Proof*. We induct on $k$. If $k=0$, then the interval is just $\{n\}$ consisting of only our starting value. Thus, assume $k>0$ and the inductive hypothesis for $k-1$. $$2^kn-2^k+1\le x\le 2^kn\implies 2^{k-1}n-2^{k-1}+1\le\left\lceil\frac x2\right\rceil\le 2^{k-1}n$$This means $\left\lceil\frac x2\right\rceil$ is the result of a sequence of keystrokes starting at $n$. If $x$ is even, $2\left\lceil\frac x2\right\rceil=2\frac x2=x$. If $x$ is odd, $2\left\lceil\frac x2\right\rceil-1=\frac{2(x+1)}2-1=x$.$\space\square$

**Lemma 2**. *There exists an integer $k\ge 0$ such that for any positive integer $x$ satisfying $x^5\le 2^kn$, $$(x+1)^5-x^5\le 2^k-1.$$*
*Proof*. First $(x+1)^5-x^5=1+5x+10x^2+10x^3+5x^4\le 31x^4\le 31\left(\sqrt[5]{2^kn}\right)^4$. Since $31x^4$ is an integer, we only need to find $k$ large enough that $\lfloor31(2^kn)^{4/5}\rfloor\le 2^k-1$ holds.

However, if $k>5\log_2(31n^{4/5})$, then $$31(2^kn)^{4/5}=2^{(4/5)k}(31n^{4/5})<2^{(4/5)k+(1/5)k}=2^k,$$ using $2^{(1/5)k}>31n^{4/5}$. It follows that $$(x+1)^5-x^5\le\lfloor31(2^kn)^{4/5}\rfloor\le 2^k-1.\space\square$$

**Theorem**. *There is a positive integer $x$ such that $x^5$ can be reached by a sequence of keystrokes starting at $n$.*
*Proof*. Let $k$ be as in Lemma 2. It suffices, by Lemma 1, to show that there is a fifth power in the interval $[2^kn-2^k+1,2^kn]$. There is a greatest integer $x$ such that $x^5<2^kn-2^k+1$. Then, $(x+1)^5-x^5\le2^k-1$, so $$(x+1)^5=(x+1)^5-x^5+x^5<2^k-1+2^kn-2^k+1=2^kn.$$ Hence, $(x+1)^5$ must be within the interval $[2^kn-2k+1,2^kn]$.$\space\square$

Comment: +1:  A couple suggestions:  In the statement of Lemma 2 I would preface it with "Given an integer $n$," to show that $k$ depends on $n$.  It is not true that $(x+1)^5-x^5=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$  Instead, $(x+1)^5-x^5=1+5x+10x^2+10x^3+5x^4$  You can rescue this by saying $k$ is large enough and changing the $5$'s to $6$'s on the right.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you! Oh wow, I managed to convince myself that was the form of the difference of fifth powers while contradicting the binomial theorem. I started off with "Hold $n$ fixed throughout," do you think that is not sufficient?

Comment: @RossMillikan I think I get what you mean about changing 5's to 6's after looking at your comment again (a few hours after changing 5's to 31's). I could have noted that $(x+1)^5-x^5$ is increasing, so I can choose $k$ large enough that for a maximal $x$ satisfying $x^5\le 2^kn$, we have $x^4\ge 10x^3+\dots$; then, I stick with this $x$.

Comment: Yes, you can use any constant larger than $5$, it just needs a larger $x$. $31$ is easy to see, and doesn't force $x$ higher, but does force $k$ higher. Either way gets you there.

Answer (score 2):

First, we characterize the space we're working with.

Let $X_n$ denote the set of $n$-tuples with entries in $\{A,B\}$ and consider the sets $$G_k=\bigcup_{j=1}^k\left\{\left(\prod_{i=1}^jx_k\right)m:x\in X_n\right\}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[m]$$
Now let's form $\bar G=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty G_k$.

> **Claim.** $$\bar G = \bigcup_j\left\{2^jm-2^{j}+1,\ldots, 2^jm\right\}.$$
>
> *Proof.* We'll prove this by induction.  Write $L_j=\left\{2^jm-i:i=\{0,\ldots,2^j-1\}\right\}$.  The base case is trivial. Now, $$\begin{eqnarray*}A L_n&=&\left\{2\times (2^nm-i):i\in\{0,\ldots,2^n-1\}\right\}\\&=&\left\{2^{n+1}m-i:i\in\{0,2,\ldots,2^{n+1}-2\}\right\}\end{eqnarray*}$$
>   and $$\begin{eqnarray*}B L_n&=&AL_n-1\\&=&\left\{2^{n+1}m-i:i\in\{1,3,\ldots,2^{n+1}-1\}\right\}\end{eqnarray*}$$
>   so $$L_{n+1}=AL_n\cup BL_n.$$

If we define $\varphi_n:\bar G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ by $\varphi_n(f)=f(n)$ and $g(x)=x^5$, we want to prove that, for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $$\varphi_n[\bar G]\cap g[\mathbb{Z}]\ne\emptyset.$$
Our strategy will be to find a big enough $j$ so that $\varphi_n[L_j]$ is large enough that it must contain a fifth root (so that $g^{-1}(x)$ is an integer for some $x\in L_j$). Of course we can find such a number so long as $$f_m(j)= g^{-1}\left(2^jm\right)-g^{-1}\left(2^j(m-1)+1\right)\geq 1$$
which, by some relatively messy calculations, is true when $g(x)=x^5$.  I've left $g$ arbitrary to make the point that not just fifth roots, but in fact any roots suffice, as well as any increasing polynomial function.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is of the form suggested by [Scaramouche's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456808/the-keys-problem#comment983110_456808), then the answer is no. Both keys are permutations on $\mathbb Z/9$, so any key sequence is also a permutation, and therefore there is some starting $x$ which gets sent to $3$. But $3$ is not a fifth power in $\mathbb Z/9$.

Comment: I do not understand the $\mathbb{Z}/9$ part. Surely you can dumb it down a little?

Comment: This just proves, that there is a $x$ and a sequence $\mathcal S$, which transforms $x$ to a number, which is not a fifth power. There may be some other sequence, that works for $x$.

Comment: @Tomas Reread the Scaramouche's comment. $\exists S$ comes before $\forall n$.

Comment: I agree and apologize. In this sense, the answer is fine. But I am not sure, that this is what the OP had in mind. The other way around seems like a more interesting problem.

Comment: @Tomas I agree with your latter statement.